# How to install TensorFlow 1.x on M1 chip?

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

For legacy reasons, I need to use TensorFlow 1.x. I followed this guide (https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706) to install TensorFlow on my M1 MacBook, however it is only able to install TensorFlow 2.x.

I am also unable to install via conda because M1 only supports Python 3.8+ for conda, whereas TensorFlow 1.x is only supported on Python 3.7 or below.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Please check this [link](https://diewland.medium.com/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-macbook-m1-87c5b0fcb3b5) on how to install `python 3.7` in Mac M1 and follow the steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install the required `TensorFlow` in conda using `python 3.7`.

Answer (score 4):

**tensorflow-macos** is only available [from tensorflow v2.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-macos/#history) but you can simulate the v1 behaviour using the following code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```